# NumberformatException JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Input file(contents):

```
8dict, 3
9GAG, 2
RT, 7
The, 2
awkward, 2
co, 14
http, 11
https, 3
irrfan_k, 2
is, 2
my, 3
rainymornings, 3
t, 14
the, 2
this, 2
you, 3
```

My Code is:

```
package pck;

import java.io.*; 
import java.util.StringTokenizer; 
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities; 
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory; 
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart; 
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class PieChart_File 
{
   public static void main( String[ ] args )throws Exception
   {
      String mobilebrands[ ] = {    
        "8dict" ,   
        "9GAGs" ,   
        "RT" ,    
        "The" ,
        "awkward",
        "co",
        "http",
        "https",
        "irrfan_k",
        "is",
        "my",
        "rainymornings",
        "t",
        "the",
        "this",
        "you"
      };

      InputStream in = new FileInputStream( new File( "C:/temp/test.txt" ) );          
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in ) );          
      StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();          
      String line;          
      DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();          

      while (( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) 
      {
         out.append( line );
      }
      StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer( out.toString(), "," );
      int i=0;      
      while( s.hasMoreTokens( ) && ( mobilebrands [i] != null ) )
      {

          dataset.setValue(mobilebrands[i], Double.parseDouble( s.nextToken( ) ));
         i++;
      }
      JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart( 
         "Repeated words",  // chart title           
         dataset,         // data           
         true,            // include legend           
         true,           
         false);

      int width = 560; /* Width of the image */          
      int height = 370; /* Height of the image */                          
      File pieChart = new File( "pie_Chart.jpeg" );                        
      ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG( pieChart, chart, width, height); 
   }
}
```

I get the following error when I try to run the file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8dict"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at pck.PieChart_File.main(PieChart_File.java:48)
```

All files are properly imported only this error shows up. The input file path is also proper.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse a String into a numeric value but the String can not be parsed of course, what is the value of "8dict" if you parse it?

You should try to parse only the first numeric value of each String.

---

### Solution using RegExs

Replace

```
dataset.setValue(mobilebrands[i], Double.parseDouble( s.nextToken( ) ));
```

With

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*"); // Finds the digits in a given String
Matcher m = p.matcher(s.nextToken());
m.find();
dataset.setValue(mobilebrands[i], Double.parseDouble(m.group(0)));
```

Comment: The method matcher(String) is undefined for the type Pattern
 The method find() is undefined for the type Selector.Matcher
 The method group(int) is undefined for the type Selector.Matcher

 at pck.PieChart_File.main(PieChart_File.java:51)

Comment: @darkrider This is not normal. Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_20

Comment: I changed the piece of code with one you mentioned but still getting this error:          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at hive.PieChart_File.main(PieChart_File.java:57)

Comment: empty String means your input is not right. Check if the String is empty before setValue of dataset

Comment: it is giving array out of bound 16 exception at this line:                                 dataset.setValue(mobilebrands[i], Double.parseDouble(m.group(0)));

Comment: The problem lays with that : mobilebrands[i] not with my solution. Check your code again or post a new question.

Comment: I updated my eclipse ide after it is giving array out of bound:16 exception

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
dataset.setValue(mobilebrands[i], Double.parseDouble( s.nextToken( ) ));
```

With

```
dataset.setValue(s.nextToken( ), Double.parseDouble( s.nextToken( )));
```

Because while entering the loop the initial value in the StringTokenizer will be 8dict not 3, which is a string not a number.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "39GAG"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at hive.PieChart_File.main(PieChart_File.java:58)

Comment: Add "," after every number you have placed in file. The concept is the input is being tokenized by ",". Since you haven't placed it after the number, it treats 3 and 9GAG as a single string. After the change it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the contents of the input file like this:

```
8dict, 3,
9GAG, 2,
RT, 7,
The, 2,
awkward, 2,
co, 14,
http, 11,
https, 3,
irrfan_k, 2,
is, 2,
my, 3,
rainymornings, 3,
t, 14,
the, 2,
this, 2,
you, 3
```

The value of variable **out** is:

```
8dict, 3,9GAG, 2,RT, 7,The, 2,awkward, 2,co, 14,http, 11,https, 3,irrfan_k, 2,is, 2,my, 3,rainymornings, 3,t, 14,the, 2,this, 2,you, 3
```

Using the **nextToken()** method you get tokens from variable **s**. The first token contains letters and digits, the second one contains only digits, and so on.

1. You have to assign the **nextToken()** method to the variable **token**.

`Object token = s.nextToken();`

You get first token which contains letters and digits (8dict).

2. You have to assign the **nextToken()** method to the variable token again.

   `token = s.nextToken();`

You get second token which contains only digits (3).

3. You can parsing this **token** into numeric value.

`Double.parseDouble(token.toString())`

Points from 1 to 3 you have to put in the while loop.

Replace this:

```
while(s.hasMoreTokens() && (mobilebrands[i] != null))
{
    dataset.setValue(mobilebrands[i], Double.parseDouble(s.nextToken()));
    i++;
}
```

with this:

```
while(s.hasMoreTokens() && (mobilebrands[i] != null))
{
    Object token = s.nextToken();
    token = s.nextToken();
    dataset.setValue(mobilebrands[i], Double.parseDouble(token.toString()));
    i++;
}
```